# Why doesn't pointer need type casting when passing it to a function with constant pointer type parameter?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, typecasting-operator

I initialize a `char[]` array with a `"hello"` string:

```c
char str[] = "hello";
func(str);
```

Now, the `char[]` array is passed to a function, taking a `const char*` pointer parameter:

```c
void func(const char* str)
{
    puts(str);
}
```

Output:

```
hello
```

Why don't I need to typecast the `char[]` array to a `const char*` pointer?

Comment: Why do you think a cast _should_ be needed?

Comment: The short answer is that the conversion is perfectly safe.

Comment: The short answer is that normally you can pass a `thing` into a function expecting a `const thing` as this is a safe operation.  However the long answer is here [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion%23Temporary_materialization) all 9 pages of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why I don't need to type cast the char type pointer to const char type pointer?

Because of the implicit **qualification conversion**. In particular, a pointer to a nonconst type can be converted to a pointer to the corresponding `const` type.

This can be seen from [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion%23Temporary_materialization):

> A prvalue of type pointer to cv-qualified type `T` can be converted to a prvalue pointer to a more cv-qualified same type `T` (in other words, constness and volatility can be added).
>
> "More" cv-qualified means that
>
> - a **pointer to unqualified type can be converted to a pointer to `const`**;
>
>   ...

(emphasis mine)

For example,

```
int i = 0;
const int *p = &i; // conversion to const happens here
```

Comment: But, when I am trying to assign a pointer of  `const int `  type into  `int *` , it shows an error. why ??

Comment: @RifatRahmanRiku Because the reverse is not true. That is, there is no implicit conversion from a `const int*` to an `int*`. In other words, an `int*` can be implicitly converted to a `const int*` but a `const int*` cannot be implicitly converted to an `int*`.

Answer (score 2):

A conversion from a pointer to a non-const can be freely converted to a pointer to a const type.  Doing so doesn't change the pointed-to type, but simply adds restrictions to how the pointed-to type is used.

For example:

```
char str[] = "test";
str[0] = 'p';   // OK
const char *p = str;
p[0] = 't';     // ERROR: pointed-to type is const
```

This applies to *all* type qualifiers, which includes `restrict` and `volatile`.

Section 6.3.2.3p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) spells this out:

> For any qualifier *q*, a pointer to a non-*q*-qualified type may be
> converted to a pointer to the *q*-qualified version of the type; the
> values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare
> equal.